# Making visible value of certain ip addresses false with cmd command in droidAtScreen application

Tags: android, cmd, command-line, adb, device

```
$ java -jar droidAtScreen-0.4.jar
```

This command opens the droidscreen application In the droidScreen, the screen of those that are visible false is not visible. While running this command, can I select a related device and set its ip address and its visible value to false with cmd command?

```
$ java -jar droidAtScreen-0.4.jar
```

When I enter this command, the droidAtScreen application opens

but I want the devices connected with adb to open the Visible value as false

Comment: I am not sure if you will get an answer to your question. As your question is written at the moment only someone with detailed knowledge on droidAtScreen may answer it, but that tool has not been updated for nearly 10 years, and you are using an even older version that is most likely more than 10 years old. So may be you you should take a look onto the tool `scrcpy` which is maintained and sounds very similar to droidAtScreen.

Comment: `$` is not a command, and has no place at the start of any command line entered within a Windows `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: Hi @Robert . I solved the problem. I entered the source code of the application, edited it according to myself and compiled it. I'm using it in scripty. But it doesn't work on some android versions